# How to add KMZ file in drupal 7?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drupal-7, kml, kmz

I have got KMZ file and I don't know how to show it from drupal. So, I research and found those codes.

```
function CoverageMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('coverageMap'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: 16.800915763233845, lng: 96.1567211141123}
   });

   var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://test.dev/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_business/coverage/ygn_mdy.kmz');
   kmzLayer.setMap(map);

}
```

I put this code and save the file *Coverage.js*. 
But, the file location is static location and I would like to change dynamic because the location will not be like this when I upload the file in server. 
 
Can I put this code `<?php echo base_path().path_to_theme() ?>`/coverage/ygn_mdy.kmz

Should KMZ file put like this as an offline or is there other ways?

Please help me to solve this problem. I've been trying to find this since 2wks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe having a dynamic path for your KMLs is not a problem as long as you place them in the correct file. Adding `<?php echo base_path().path_to_theme() ?>` into a javascript file **Coverage.js** will likely wont work because it will just be treated as an ordinary string.

I would suggest all the javascript codes that there's a PHP involvement should be saved in a PHP file. In your case, saving it to something like Coverage.php and the code should look something like this:

```
function CoverageMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 16.800915763233845, lng: 96.1567211141123 }
  });
  var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("<?php echo $base_path().$path_to_theme().'/coverage/ygn_mdy.kmz'; ?>");
  kmzLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

Check **[Google Maps Javascript API KML Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml)** to learn more. You can also check **[Displaying KML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml)** to learn more on displaying information of a KML file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this helps you, would you mind upvoting/accepting it? Thanks :)